# FB.init in IFrame cause to infinite loop at IE8 and after sometime to Flash error message

Tags: javascript, facebook, internet-explorer-8, infinite-loop, facebook-iframe

I am not using any Flash at my application. The code that cause the issue is the simplest one that you can find at the end.

I configured my application to work in IFrame exactly as it mentioned at the facebook developer site.

The problem is that when I add the init option the page doesn't stop to do ajax call (infinite loop) to the server in IE8 and if I am playing with it for a while and moving up & down after I am clicking on the button to submit the form I see those kind of errors:

> Error #2044: Unhandled
>   SecurityErrorEvent:. text=Error #2047:
>   Security sandbox violation:
>   LocalConnection.send: ak.fbcdn.net
>   cannot access
>   http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yF/r/Y7YCBKX-HZn.swf.

or

> Error #2044: Unhandled StatusEvent:.
>   level=error, code=

Again I am not using any Flash/Flex/SWF in my facebook application and I am using the most simple code that contain just JS without any changes.

```
<!DOCTYPE unspecified PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>


<body>
<!-- stylesheets for the UI -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId  : 'YOUR APP ID',
      status : true, // check login status
      cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
    });
  };

  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>

<form>
    <button type="submit"> WOW</button>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your app settings in the Facebook Developer app: I've noticed similar problems if you have the **Site Domain** field set incorrectly. The page simply keeps refreshing over and over and over again.

I couldn't figure out what value to put there to make it stop doing that so I simply cleared that field and the problem went away.